# How to disable weak ciphers and client renegotiation in Play 2.5.x (Scala)

Tags: java, scala, https, playframework

I am using Play 2.5.x (Scala). The default server is Netty. I can't find a way to disable some (weak) specific ciphers as well as client renegotiation.
The Play doc refers to JSSE settings:
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ConfiguringHttps

How do I use these JSSE settings in a config file ? Or is there a different way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/CipherSuites#Disabling-Weak-Ciphers-and-Weak-Key-Sizes-Globally), create a properties file (let's call it `jvm.security.properties`) that looks something like the following:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=EC keySize < 160, RSA keySize < 2048, DSA keySize < 2048
jdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
jdk.certpath.disabledAlgorithms=MD2, MD4, MD5, EC keySize < 160, RSA keySize < 2048, DSA keySize < 2048
```

Then start up the JVM with that properties file:

```
java -Djava.security.properties=jvm.security.properties
```

Comment: Thanks. I missed the doc section which you pointed out thinking that it is applicable for WS client. 
I tried running this from inside "target/universal/play-scala-82-SNAPSHOT/" using command:
>bin/play-scala
NOTE: play-scala is the name of executable script that is generated when I run "sbt dist". But it does not work - it does not enable those security properties.
I edited the file bin/play-scala as:
echo "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Djava.security.properties=<my-location>/play-scala-app/target/universal/play-scala-82-SNAPSHOT/conf/disabledAlgorithms.properties"

Comment: Second, in production I use "sbt docker:publishLocal" to build my webapp. There how do I provide this setting ?

Comment: I also tried these but didn't work:
`sudo bin/play-scala -Djava.security.properties=conf/disabledAlgorithms.properties`
`sudo bin/play-scala -Djava.security.properties=disabledAlgorithms.properties`

Comment: On the other hand when I pass properties as below it applies:   

`sudo bin/play-scala -Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048 -Djdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms="EC keySize < 160, RSA keySize < 2048, DSA keySize < 2048"`

Comment: Any suggestions ?